# How to delete rows in two sheets based on cell value in one of those sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently an email is sent when values are entered into a couple of cells in sheet5 (through a form via appsheet). This works perfectly (thanks to some help on this site!) but I'm now struggling with adding the following functions to the whole thing even though it seems like it should be straightforward. I'll explain each step briefly for what I'm looking to happen:

1. On sheet5 cells A2 and B2 are filled via a form.
2. An email is sent in response, based on data entered onto sheet2.
3. Cells A2 and B2 on sheet5 are then cleared, as is the table on sheet2 (cells A2:G200).

I've tried based on others answers on this site and can't get even half of step 3 working currently. I don't know if the deletion would be better on a timed/delayed thing either (say, 30 seconds) since it's important the email is sent before there's any chance of it being deleted.

I've pasted what I have so far below:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet4=ss.getSheetByName('Copy');
  var emailAddress = sheet4.getRange(2,12).getValue();
  var subject = sheet4.getRange(2,13).getValue();
  var message = sheet4.getRangeList(['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7', 'G8'])
    .getRanges()
    .map(range => range.getDisplayValue())
    .join('\n');
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

function onChange(e) {

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === `Trigger`) {
    if (e.source.getActiveRange().getRow() >= 1 && e.source.getActiveRange().getColumn() >= 1) {
      if (e.source.getActiveRange().getValue() !== ``) sendEmail()
    }
  }
}
```

Many thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh4 = ss.getSheetByName('Copy');
  var email = sh4.getRange(2, 12).getValue();
  var subject = sh4.getRange(2, 13).getValue();
  var message = sh4.getRangeList(['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7', 'G8'])
    .getRanges()
    .map(range => range.getDisplayValue())
    .join('\n');
  //Logger.log('email:%s\nsubject: %s\nmessage:%s',email, subject, message);
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

function onMyChange(e) {
  //e.source.toast('onMyChange');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const ar = sh.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName() === `Trigger` && e.changeType == "EDIT") {
    if (ar.getRow() > 0 && ar.getColumn() > 0) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      if (ar.getValue() !== ``) sendEmail()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I tried that and it doesn't seem to do anything (including sending the email - I did try changing "email" to "emailAddress" and it didn't make any difference).